# LCD only turn on in hot weather

Tags: temperature, lg-monitor

I have an LG LCD and when the weather is cold it will take a long time to turn on and I need to turn on and turn off several times before the image appears.

When I'm doing this the image appears for a little bit and goes a way again.

When the weather is hot I rarely have this problem. After the image is showing it does not disappear again until I turn it off again.

Any suggestions to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Keep it near the heater to keep it warm. Or, more seriously, get it repaired in service? That kind of behaviour is not normal.

Comment: Is the weather *outside* cold but inside it's stable? Or is the monitor itself being subjected to these large temperature swings? The manufacturer's specifications will tell you whether the monitor is rated to work in the lower temperatures.

Comment: @kajaco The temperature is nice inside, but when the weather outside is hot, the house becomes warmer and I don't have this problem. Tomorrow I will try to warm it just a little bit with a hair dryer.

Answer (score 3):

> - What I think is your Monitor probably needs a service. This kind of
>     behavior is not normal.
> - In the cold Season Moisture gets inside and freezes damaging some
>     circuits.
> - Some LCD screens become permanently discolored as a result of exposure to
>     the cold.
> - Unlike CRTs, there's a physical substance inside LCD which can and
>     will change state based on
>     temperature.
> - Also When LCDs are cold, the pixels are very slow to react.
> - **The Only suggestion I could think** of is try keeping it near a low heater to reduce
>     the effect of sudden temperature
>     change

A Good Site featuring excellent tips to  care your LCD screen http://www.lcdtvbuyingguide.com/lcdtvcaring.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If the power cable can be unplugged from the back of the monitor, try unplugging it and plugging it back in, re-seating it as firmly as possible.  Warm-cold cycles can eventually cause small amounts of movement in physical components that are not clamped into place.  Also, some power connectors/plugs fit rather loosely at best.  Anyway, it's worth a shot.  The video cable is less likely to be the problem, but it's worth checking as well - on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Just chipping in my two cents. The  instructions of the LG 25UM65 LED model states that "the monitor may flicker in an area where the temperature is low. This is normal."
[Excerpt from manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfZLN.png)
(This is also quoted in the manual for other similar models.)
In my experience "Low temperature" means below 17 °C in room temperature. These models also turn of the screen if flickering occurs, so you will only see flickering shortly before a black screen. Image may or may not reappear, without turning monitor off and on again. As the temperature rises both in the room and the monitor, the problem gradually goes away.